# How to slide the image in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to slide an image into left side:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#one").show("fade",500);
     $("#one").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
  });  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="slider">
   <img id="one" src="img/banner01.jpg" alt="first image"/>
   <img id="two" src="img/banner02.jpg" alt="first image"/>
   <img id="three" src="img/banner03.jpg" alt="first image"/>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it gives an error on browser console
  Uncaught TypeError: Property '#' of object # is not a function 
plz help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#one").show("fade",500);
     $("#one").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
  });  
}); // <--- remove this line
```

Edit:

You are loading jQuery UI 1.7.2, I don't think that this version supports jQuery 1.4.2, try loading newer version of jQuery Core library.

Comment: nope. line is correct.

Comment: @DheerajSharma Why do you think so? It's not.

Comment: yeah..my posting error but its not real error its               Uncaught TypeError: Property '500' of object #<Object> is not a function jquery-1.4.1.min.js:141

Answer (score 1):

JQuery/CSS

```
<script>
        $(function() {      
            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide(); 
            setInterval(function() { 
              $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1500)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1500)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
            },  3000);          
        });
    </script> 
        <style>
            #slideshow {position: absolute; width: 264px; height: 104px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;}
            #slideshow > div { position: absolute; overflow: hidden;}   
        </style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="tile tile-white">
   <div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="tpl/main/img/pic1.png" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="tpl/main/img/pic2.png" />
   </div>
      <div>
     <img src="tpl/main/img/pic3.png" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="tpl/main/img/pic4.png" />
   </div>
      <div>
     <img src="tpl/main/img/pic5.png" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="tpl/main/img/pic6.png" />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: not an issue.I can do this by using internet but i want the solution of error in mycode it should slide with my simple code also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the jquery plugins like as follows

[nivo slider](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/)